# Using Linq how I have to add list items

Tags: c#, linq, c#-4.0

```
IEnumerable<ReportFavorite> list = reportService.GetReportFavorites(userId);
ddlReportFavorite.Items.Add()
```

I don't know how to add the lists to the dropdown using Linq. Thanks.

Comment: For future reference, you will get better answers if you provide more information.. What UI technology are you using? WPF, WinForms, Silverlight, ASP.NET WebForms, ASP.NET MVC? all of these have different controls.

Comment: What is a type of `ddlReportFavorite.Items`?

Comment: @sll,Previously I put as IEnumerable. Now I changed to IList. It is working fine now.Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on the dropdown control you are using, either of these could work:

If it allows its Items to be set to an `IEnumerabe<ReportFavourite>`:

```
ddlReportFavorite.Items = reportService.GetReportFavorites(userId);
```

If Items implements the AddRange method:

```
ddlReportFavorite.Items.AddRange(reportService.GetReportFavorites(userId));
```

Or, if these fail

```
foreach(var reportFavourite in reportService.GetReportFavorites(userId))
    ddlReportFavorite.Items.Add(reportFavourite);
```

Neither of these methods is really "using LINQ", because LINQ is not a good tool to do this. LINQ is meant to be side-effect free.

**Edit:**
Your comment suggests that you are using a `System.Web.UI.WebControls.DropDownList`. In this case, the Items collection only accepts instances `ListItem`, so you need to create these from your ReportFavourites. Try

```
foreach(var listItem in reportService.GetReportFavorites(userId)
                                     .Select(r => new ListItem(r.Id, r.Name))
    ddlReportFavorite.Items.Add(listItem);
```

Here, I assume the combo box should display ReportFavourite.Name and have a value of ReportFavourite.Id. Use your own properties, of course

Comment: I am getting some invalid arguments in both cases. Thanks.

Comment: I tried the last option also. Again it shows, the best overload method match for 'system.web.ui.webcontrols.listitemCollection.add(system.web.ui.webcontrols.listitemCollection)' has some invalid arguments. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

You an use `AddRange` method:

```
 var list = reportService.GetReportFavorites(userId);
 ddlReportFavorite.Items.AddRange(list.ToArray());
```

Comment: I am getting some invalid arguments issue.

Answer (score 1):

Or if you've already checked the data's integrity in the method, you could just simply say:

```
ddlReportFavorite.Items.AddRange(reportService.GetReportFavorites(userId));
```

Comment: I am getting some invalid arguments issue.

Answer (score 1):

Previously I put as IEnumerable. Now I changed to IList. It is working fine now. Thanks to all.

```
    int userId = workContext.CurrentUser.UserID;
    var reportFavoriteList = reportService.GetReportFavorites(userId);
    int count = reportFavoriteList.Count;

    for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
    {
        ddlReportFavorite.Items.Add(reportFavoriteList[i].FavoriteName);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Since `ddlReprotFavorite is an UI control and its`Items`property represent a set of controls as well you ca`n not add directly your business entities instead of use DataSource property which automatically create Items collection from the underlying business entities.

```
IEnumerable<ReportFavorite> list = reportService.GetReportFavorites(userId);      
ddlReportFavorite.DataSource = list;
```

Answer (score 0):

The `IEnumerable<T>` is extended by the method `Union<T>` which unions two `IEnumerable<T>`'s. This is the more pretty way, without casting it `ToList()`.

```
var reportFavoriteList = reportService.GetReportFavorites(userId);
ddlReportFavorite.Items = ddlReportFavorite.Items.Union(reportFavoriteList);
```